# Creating a new csv and writing a variable result to the file

Tags: python, csv

I am running a python script to scan for a fakeAP in an area. Currently, the script has been configured to send an email notification to admin through the following code. I would like to create a new .csv file and save the result (message) to a csv file instead and get rid off all code for sending message notification. I have tried to write a simple script to help solve this problem but nothing seem to work. Any help solve this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
# sending an alert to the admin email   
def AlertAdmin(message):
try:
cmd = "select opt_val from options where opt_key = 'admin_email'"
cursor.execute(cmd)
if cursor.rowcount > 0:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    admin_email = row[0]
    cmd = "select opt_val from options where opt_key = 'admin_smtp'"
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    admin_smtp = row[0]
    cmd = "select opt_val from options where opt_key = 'admin_smtp_username'"
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        admin_smtp_username = row[0]
        cmd = "select opt_val from options where opt_key = 'admin_smtp_password'"
        cursor.execute(cmd)
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        admin_smtp_password = row[0]
        message = "From: EvilAP_Defender <{}>\nTo: Admin <{}>\nSubject: EvilAP_Defender Alert!\n\n"\
            .format(admin_smtp_username, admin_email) + message
        try:
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nConnecting to SMTP server\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv = smtplib.SMTP(admin_smtp,587)
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nSending ehlo message to SMTP server\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.ehlo()
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nStarting TLS with SMTP server\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.starttls()
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nSending ehlo message to SMTP server\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.ehlo()
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nLogin to SMTP server\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.login(admin_smtp_username,admin_smtp_password)
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nSending the message ...\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.sendmail(admin_smtp_username, admin_email, message)
            print bcolors.OKBLUE + "\nDisconnecting from mail server ...\n" + bcolors.ENDC
            mailsrv.quit()
            print bcolors.OKGREEN + bcolors.BOLD + "\nSuccessfully sent email to admin\n" + bcolors.ENDC
        except:
            print bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "\nError: unable to send an email to admin: {}\n".format(sys.exc_info()[0]) + bcolors.ENDC
            #print bcolors.OKGREEN + bcolors.BOLD + "\nSuccessfully sent email to admin\n" + bcolors.ENDC
        else:
        print bcolors.WARNING + "Cannot send alert. SMTP password not found!\nConfigure admin notification from Learning Mode\n" + bcolors.ENDC
    else:
        print bcolors.WARNING + "Cannot send alert. SMTP username not found!\nConfigure admin notification from Learning Mode\n" + bcolors.ENDC
    else:
    print bcolors.WARNING + "Cannot send alert. SMTP address not found!\nConfigure admin notification from Learning Mode\n" + bcolors.ENDC
else:
    print bcolors.WARNING + "Cannot send alert. Admin email not found!\nConfigure admin notification from Learning Mode\n" + bcolors.ENDC
except:
print bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "Unexpected error in 'AlertAdmin': {}\n".format(sys.exc_info()[0]) + bcolors.ENDC
#print bcolors.OKGREEN + bcolors.BOLD + "\nSuccessfully sent email to admin\n" + bcolors.ENDC

return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `try-except` block with the following code:

```
try:
    ofile  = open('messagelog.csv', "ab")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    record = [admin_smtp_username, admin_email, message]
    writer.writerow(record)
    ofile.close()
except:
    print bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "\nError: unable to write message to log file: {}\n".format(sys.exc_info()[0]) + bcolors.ENDC
```

Note: don't forget to `import csv`

Comment: Thank you Anubhav, the above piece of code did the trick. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

The very basics would be something like following in python3.6 in terms of file write. Read is similar with mode 'r' . . .

```
import csv
with open('myfile.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('line1')
    f.write('line2')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..much appreciated :)